# How to get work Konica Minolta bizhub 423 printer working?

Tags: printing, konica

I am trying many times to install the driver of Konica Minolta bizhub 423  on ubuntu but I have not succeeded to get a printout. Although communication can be established, it does not print. There are URI setting of which i am not much familiar. Does anybody has an idea or was able to get it run?

Answer (score 5):

I am using 12.04 on a Windows network and this is what worked for me:

1. Download the **bizhub 423** Linux drivers from [here](http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/download/SearchResults.aspx?productid=1312).
2. Add new printer and select the Konica Minolta 423 (it should appear as a network printer).
3. Ubuntu will search for drivers, but eventually will ask you to provide a PPD. Navigate to the downloaded driver file and install:

   `423_Series_Linux_v10000.0000/CUPS1.2/English/KO423UX.ppd`
4. Ignore the installable options (paper source unit, etc) and click OK - you can come back to them later if needs be.
5. At this point I still had no communication with the printer so I changed the device URI (under Printer Properties) to `lpd://192.168.1.3/print`. You may need to replace `192.168.1.3` with whatever your printer's IP address is, but once I got this right it was printing.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is now dead. The new link is http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/Downloadfile_2/Download.ashx?fileversionid=3272&productid=1313

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work with Ubuntu 15.04? These instructions result in all jobs saying "Processing" forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to inform you that this procedure works fine under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. There was no driver for our Konica Minolta Bizhub c224e, but I selected the driver "KONICA MINOLTA 500/420/360PS(P)" that was available on the list and works like a charm printing in full colour.

Just remember to change Device URI from the default one to something like lpd://10.1.0.13/print - you can check the IP address in the menu on the printer display.

Another trick is to know what printer options are installed and enable them in the driver's menus. In my case these were additional paper bins and duplex.