# How do I install drivers for a Konica Minolta 200?

Tags: printing, konica

This copy machine / scanner / network printer works with Windows but no drivers are available for linux.
When Ubuntu supports a printer it works fine but this one is not supported.

I found the drivers in:
http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/download/SearchResults.aspx?productname=bizhub%20200

//But I don't know how to install them, nor which one to download.
//How can I install this driver?

EDIT:
The file with the driver is here
http://onyxftp.mykonicaminolta.com/DownloadFile/Download.ashx?fileid=18571&productid=865
Inside the archive there is a .deb package that installs correctly but doesn't work.

So far the question is: "How can I make it work?"

Comment: are you sure about the model?  is it a c200?  Maybe the inbuilt konica c250 driver will work - worth a try.

Comment: @fossfreedom : No. The driver c250 did not work. The model is a bizhub 200, not C200. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked Konica Minolta Tech support (in spanish) about this and they answered me with this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fticrycjyxlp8n2/423_Series_Linux_v10000.zip

The ppd file I must specify is KO423SX.ppd

To install, add a printer the specify an uri such as lpd://192.168.1.40/print (replacing 192.168.1.40 with your printer's ip address).
Then specify the KO423SX.ppd file as the ppd file.

Adjust settings and print. In my case it claims there's no paper in the printer but still prints correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As I've just described here: [How to get work Konica Minolta bizhub 423 printer working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144321/how-to-get-work-konica-minolta-bizhub-423-printer-working/932641) it is possible to use another driver.

There was no driver for our Konica Minolta Bizhub c224e, but I selected the driver "KONICA MINOLTA 500/420/360PS(P)" that was available on the list and works like a charm printing in full colour.

Just remember to change Device URI from the default one to something like lpd://10.1.0.13/print - you can check the IP address in the menu on the printer display.

Another trick is to know what printer options are installed and enable them in the driver's menus. In my case these were additional paper bins and duplex.